# Error : Putting files in the HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am facing an issue while trying to run a sample Hadoop source code on an ARM processor. Every time I am trying to put some files in the HDFS, I am getting the below error.

```
13/10/07 11:31:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/root/bin/cpu-kmeans2D could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:422)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:2904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2262)

13/10/07 11:31:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
13/10/07 11:31:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/root/bin/cpu-kmeans2D" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /user/root/bin/cpu-kmeans2D could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

I tried replicating the namenode and datanode by deleting all the old logs on the master and the slave nodes as well as the folders under `/app/hadoop/`, after which I formatted the namenode and started the process again (`bin/start-all.sh`), but still no luck with the same.

I tried generating the admin report(pasted below) after doing the restart, it seems the data node is not getting started.

```
-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)

root@tegra-ubuntu:~/hadoop-gpu-master/hadoop-gpu-0.20.1# bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: �%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)
```

I have tried all possible ways to debug this. I have tried the following methods :

1) I logged in  to the HADOOP home directory and removed all the old logs (`rm -rf logs/*`)

2) Next I deleted the contents of the directory on all my slave and master nodes (`rm -rf /app/hadoop/*`)

3) I formatted the namenode (`bin/hadoop namenode -format`)

4) I started all the processes - first the namenode, datanode and then the map - reduce.  I typed jps on the terminal to ensure that all the processes (Namenode, Datanode, JobTracker, Task Tracker) are up and running.

5) Now doing this, I recreated the directories in the dfs.

Comment: Could you please show me the DN logs?

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:10:26,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data is not formatted.
2013-10-08 12:10:26,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Formatting ...
2013-10-08 12:10:26,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Registered FSDatasetStatusMBean
2013-10-08 12:10:26,408 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened info server at 50010
2013-10-08 12:10:26,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:10:26,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2013-10-08 12:10:26,700 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-10-08 12:10:27,047 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50075
2013-10-08 12:10:27,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50075 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50075

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:10:27,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50075
2013-10-08 12:10:27,049 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.14
2013-10-08 12:14:19,697 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075
2013-10-08 12:14:19,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=DataNode, sessionId=null
2013-10-08 12:14:19,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcMetrics: Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=DataNode, port=50020

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:14:19,788 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-10-08 12:14:19,789 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2013-10-08 12:14:19,800 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 50020: starting
2013-10-08 12:14:19,800 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020: starting

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:14:19,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnRegistration = DatanodeRegistration(tegra-ubuntu:50010, storageID=, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)
2013-10-08 12:14:19,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 50020: starting
2013-10-08 12:14:19,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: New storage id DS-348544278-127.0.1.1-50010-1381259659806 is assigned to data-node 10.227.56.195:50010

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:14:19,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.227.56.195:50010, storageID=DS-348544278-127.0.1.1-50010-1381259659806, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)In DataNode.run, data = FSDataset{
dirpath='/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/current'}
2013-10-08 12:14:19,849 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: using BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 3600000msec Initial delay: 0msec
2013-10-08 12:14:19,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: BlockReport of 0 blocks got processed in 19 msecs

Comment: 2013-10-08 12:14:19,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting Periodic block scanner.

Comment: Hi Tariq, above are all the DN logs. Can you kindly suggest as how I can proceed forward ?